# Requesting non-personalized ads failing AdMob

Tags: admob

I'm using AdMob in my app, and getting consent from the user using the package. Then setting `nonPersonalized Ads` depending on the user's consent.

However, whenever the user says no to personalized ads, AdMob always fails to get an ad, saying "No Ad Config Found". Searching about this, it seems that AdMob is unable to create an ad that is not personalized.

How can I solve this? There doesn't seem to be any forums or documentation about why this is happening and how to solve it.

Comment: You ever figure this out? Having same issue.